# Class not Found Error when updated kafka_2.12 dependency

Tags: scala, gradle, apache-kafka

I updated the dependency in my `build.gradle` file from `kafka_2.11` to `kafka_2.12`.

I am getting the following error when I try to run a testcase after this :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/TraversableOnce$class
```

Comment: Looks like a library not compiled with the correct version of Scala, could you share more details ? Like what code is generating this issue ?

Comment: Can you share the dependencies as defined in `build.gradle`?

Comment: You need to upgrade the scala-library dependencies as well

Comment: *kafka_2.11* is for *Scala 2.11* and  *kafka_2.12* is for *Scala 2.12*. Did you updated Scala to 2.12 as well?

Comment: I originally had this dependency in my build.gradle file

Comment: testCompile(group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.11', version: "$KAFKA_VERSION", classifier: 'test') {
        exclude group: 'log4j'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }                                                                                                                                          I changed kafka_2.11 to kafka_2.12 and KAFKA_VERSION to 2.0.1